Save picture from excel to a file
I have an excel where I import some pictures (from a onedrive file, they are uploaded as part of a query). These pictures are part of an auto-response PDF I will generate from my excel file, that works good.
However, I also would like to save the picture itself somewhere on my drive and there I'm running (apparently) into limitations with regards to the Picture format/my own very limited VBA knowledge.
'Put in new picture, save, copy to appropriate location


PicPath = Worksheets("Transfersheet").Range("PHOTOLD1URL").Value


Set myPicture = Worksheets("Lay-out").Pictures.Insert(PicPath)
    
    With myPicture
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Height = Worksheets("Lay-out").Range("B24:F34").Height
        .Top = Worksheets("Lay-out").Range("B24:F34").Top
        .Left = Worksheets("Lay-out").Range("B24:F34").Left
    End With

Any idea if there is a quick workabout to write the 'myPicture' to a file?

Is this an X-Y Problem? By which: Do you need the Picture from Excel, or are you just trying to copy it from OneDrive to another location?  (i.e. would the FileCopy statement or something similar be enough? Or, would you be better off doing something like importing the Picture as Shape in a Chart — not as a Shape in a Worksheet — and then using the Chart.SaveAs method to Save the resulting Chart as an Image file?)

FileCopy doesn't seem to work with OneDrive hhtp extensions

Based on Comments and Responses, it seems that you would be better off downloading the file to your own drive, and then importing it to Excel.  You also indicate that, since you are using web-sources, you cannot use FileCopy.
As such, here is code to download a file over the Internet, and save it to a Location on your machine:
Public Function DownloadFile(ByVal DownloadURL As String, ByVal SaveAsLocation As String) As Boolean
    DownloadFile = False
    On Error GoTo FuncErr
    
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object, oStream As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", DownloadURL, False
    WinHttpReq.Send
    
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile SaveAsLocation, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If

    DownloadFile = True
FuncErr:
    On Error Resume Next
    oStream.Close
    WinHttpReq.Close
    On Error GoTo -1
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set oStream = Nothing
    Set WinHttpReq = Nothing
End Function

You would then use it something like this:
PicPath = Worksheets("Transfersheet").Range("PHOTOLD1URL").Value
DestPath = Worksheets("Transfersheet").Range("PHOTOLD1Dest").Value 

If DownloadFile(PicPath, DestPath) Then
    With Worksheets("Lay-out").Pictures.Insert(DestPath)
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Height = Worksheets("Lay-out").Range("B24:F34").Height
        .Top = Worksheets("Lay-out").Range("B24:F34").Top
        .Left = Worksheets("Lay-out").Range("B24:F34").Left
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Unable to download Picture!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & PicPath, vbCritical, "Picture Import Error"
End If


Thank you! I keep getting saddled with error 3004 however, but the filepaths seem to match and my permissions to read/write are in order.
